# component visible if boolCheckBox is checked

Tags: primefaces, visible

I have a web page, which contains several components, when I click on boolCheckbox, I want to disappear some other components, I tried to use the rendered attribute but it's doesn't work.

is there a visible attribute (or its equivalent) for simple component like : boolCheckBox, inputText, ... ?

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Bean.check}" >
    <p:ajax update="check2" listener="#{Bean.function()}"/>  
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check2" value="#{Bean.check2}" rendered="#{Bean.check}">
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Post relevant code, 'doesn't work' is not a valid problem description.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech, I've just posted my code.

Answer (score 2):

You're updating the component that should not be displayed after the value change. You should update the parent component. For example:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Bean.check}" >
    <p:ajax update="check2-parent" listener="#{Bean.function()}"/>  
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:panel id="check2-parent">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check2" value="#{Bean.check2}" rendered="#{Bean.check}"/>
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('checkbox').on('click', function() {
 if($(this).is(':checked')) {
  // checked do something
  $('.classname').hide();
 }
 else {
  // not checked do something else
  $('.classname').show();
 }
});
```

Comment: But how to hide and show a component with JQuery inside JSF. can give me more details ?